# Best way to approach to avoid token generation

Tags: mule, mule4

We are developing a system API that hits the Azure backend to fetch the data. In order to hit the azure currently we are generating tokens for each request which is valid for 3599 seconds.

Instead, how I can design the flow to get the token only when the current token is expired?
What's the best approach?

I am thinking like set the timestamp next to http listener and for each request check the previous timestamp value is less than current if true then go with the old token if false generate a new one.

This is a typical solution. Is there anyway to tackle this more efficiently using mule 4?

TIA!

Comment: How are you generating token?  Is it oauth or some custom implementation?

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @HarshankBansal there is an Azure API which we hit to get the token. Same like a simple POST call

Comment: Why not use cache scope? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/cache-scope

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cache scope or implement your own token storage using the Object Store connector. This provides an Entry TTL setting if you want to set a constant expiration time, or you can use an optimistic strategy and only refresh the token when you get a 401 error.